# Volume with a Cubic

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid of revolution formed when the curve $y=x^3+1$ is rotated around the $y$-axis from $y=1$ to $y=9$.

I understand the rule to find the volume when it is rotated around the $y$-axis; however, how do I make the subject and squared when it is cubed?

Does that make sense?

Comment: You can use the method of BRICS-Fan, or use Cylindrical Shells, $\int_0^2 2\pi x(x^3+1)\,dx$.

Answer (score 3):

Make cylindrical shells of radius $x$ $\>(0\leq x\leq2)$, height $9-(x^3+1)=8-x^3$, and thickness $dx$. The volume $V$ in question then appears as
$$V=\int_0^2 2\pi x(8-x^3)\>dx=2\pi\left(4x^2-{x^5\over5}\right)\Biggr|_0^2={96\over5}\pi\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

We're working on the $y$ axis, so let's change orientations first.

$$x = (y-1)^{1/3}$$

Since we're asked to find the volume of revolution, we need to determine the radius and area of the revolution at each point along the given interval $y \in [1, 9]$. The radius is simply given by the "height" of the function $x$, so the area is given by $\pi x^2 = \pi (y-1)^{2/3}$. Integrating along the interval, we find

$$ \int_{y=1}^9 \pi (y-1)^{2/3} \,\mathrm{d}x = \left.\frac{3\pi}{5}(y-1)^{5/3}\right|_{1}^{9} = \frac{96\pi}{5} $$

Comment: There is no reason to swap the $x$ and $y$. It has only served to confuse things. Upon changing the orientation, the area is given by $\pi y^2=\pi(x-1)^{2/3}$ and the integral should be $$\int_{\color{#C00000}{x}=1}^9\pi(\color{#C00000}{x}-1)^{2/3}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $y=x^3+1$, we have $\mathrm{d}y=3x^2\mathrm{d}x$. Therefore, using the [Disc Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration) for finding the volume of rotation, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^9\pi x^2\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_0^2\pi x^2\,3x^2\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[3\pi\frac{x^5}5\right]_0^2\\[4pt]
&=\frac{96\pi}5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't know if the downvote was because I gave a hint, but since there are now two complete answers, I might as well complete the answer to demonstrate the whole idea.

Answer (score -3):

**hint**: $V = \displaystyle \int_{1}^9 \pi(\sqrt[3]{y-1})^2dy$